# Site Owners(added explicitly in OOTB SP Owner group) are not able to delete the site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, site-collection, administration

I have a scenario where the user is the owner of the site, granted Full Control permission via default SP Owners group but when the user tries to delete the site, it gives an access denied error.

I guess earlier, owners were allowed to delete the site. Are there any changes around this?

P.S. If the user is added as SCA explicitly, then the user is able to delete the site.

I tried in my dev tenant and got the below errors while deleting the site as an owner.

While Deleting a site without an M365 group:

[image]

While deleting a site associated with the M365 group:

[image]

Comment: Hi @DhruvilPrajapati, Any update on below response? Is it working as per the response/Microsoft documentation?

Answer (score -2):

> You must be a site owner or SharePoint administrator to delete sites. If you are a site owner but you are unable to delete a site, your administrator may have turned off the ability to do so.
>
> **Notes**:
>
> - To delete a communication site, you must be a site owner and ***also*** a site admin. To delete a team site, you must be a site owner (team site owners are automatically site admins, confirm that M365 owners group is not removed from SCA before deleting)
> - When you delete a group connected team site, there can be a delay before the site is removed from SharePoint.

**Microsoft official documentation**: [Delete a SharePoint site or subsite](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/delete-a-sharepoint-site-or-subsite-bc37b743-0cef-475e-9a8c-8fc4d40179fb)

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the user is added as the Owner SP group and is still not able to delete the site.

Comment: Use should also be a site admin (SCA) to delete the site

Comment: That I am aware of Ganesh!!! with Modern sites, but with Team sites without M365 groups as well it requires SCA access.

Comment: All types of modern sites in SP online (communication/team with M365 group/team without M365 group) requires SCA access. Only thing is when you create a team site with M365 group, M365 owners group is automatically added to SCA of site. For other type of sites, only user who created site is automatically added to SCA. You have to manually add other users to SCA in that case.

Comment: Also note that - in case of team site with M365 group, M365 owners group (not SP Owner group) is automatically added to SCA of site. However, site admins can manually remove it from SCA - hence you have to confirm the SCA membership before deleting the site

Comment: People blindly downvoting should test this functionality first. I have tested it for all types of sites (communication, team with M365 group and without M365 group) before answering this question (tested on targeted release tenant). Even Microsoft official documentation states the same that you need to have Site Admin (SCA) permissions to delete a site in SharePoint Online!

Comment: Hi @DhruvilPrajapati, did you test & validate these scenarios? does this response and Microsoft official documentation answers your question?

Comment: Hi @DhruvilPrajapati, any update on this thread?